# How to keep the field enabled if it has a value after edit in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

if i select 3rd dropdown value in the first field dropdown then the 2nd field is enabled.
So, now if i give value by selecting 3rd value of dropdown, and give a value to 2nd field it is taken.
Now i go to edit function and change some other value as the 2nd field is disabled i am getting ass null or undefined.
So now i want 2nd field to have its value if 1st field is not changed in edit mode

HTML:

TS:

```
private FormInit() {
    //Add
    if (!this.Details) {
      this.detailsForm = this.FB.group({
        Type: ['', Validators.required],
        ID: [{ value: 0, disabled: true }],
      });

    } else {
      // edit
      this.detailsForm = this.FB.group({
        Type: [this.Details.data.Type, Validators.required],
        SourceID: [{ value: this.Details.data.ID, disabled: true }],

      });
      if (this.Details.mode == 'readOnly') {
        this.detailsForm.disable();
      }
    }
  }
```

ADD and Edit functions:

```
public save() {
    let addParams = this.detailsForm.value;
   addParams.Type = addParams.Type ? addParams.Type: 0;
    this.Service.add(addParams).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
      this.successMessagePopUp(res);
    })
  }

  public update() {
    let updateParams = this.detailsForm.value;

    this.Service.update(updateParams).subscribe(res => {
      this.successMessagePopUp(res)
    })
  }
```

Hope this cn be solved in one way, if 3rd dropdown value is selected, then in edit mode can we keep the 2nd field enaled and disable oly if other value is selected?

Comment: when you are getting null? on submit?

Comment: @Sravan i had updated my question please check

Comment: @Sravan will that logic work?

Comment: @Sravan please check sourceTypeValidation(), here if value is 3, then soureceId field is enabled or else source iD will be disabled so that this field is not passed, so it gives value as empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally **`disabled`** values will show undefined in `angular`.

PS: I think according to your requirement:

```
private FormInit() {
    if (!this.Details) {
      this.detailsForm = this.FB.group({
        Type: ['', Validators.required],
        ID: [{ value: 0, disabled: true }],
      });

    } else {
      // edit
      this.detailsForm = this.FB.group({
        Type: [this.Details.data.Type, Validators.required],
        ID: [{ value: this.Details.data.ID }],

      });

     if (this.Details.data.Type == 3)
     {
         this.detailsForm.get("ID").enable();
     }
     else
     {
         this.detailsForm.get("ID").disable();
     }

      if (this.Details.mode == 'readOnly') {
        this.detailsForm.disable();
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for response il check

Comment: ya i will check

Comment: where you are not getting disabled value?

Comment: in soueceId field

Comment: i edited, some other field, but the value in sourceID is also changing

Comment: in `addParams` you are not getting?

Comment: in add params i am able to add, if i edit there if i select dropdown value 1 or 2, then the sourceID field must be empty

Comment: must be empty means?

Comment: that field will be disabled

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176790/discussion-between-sravan-and-bhrungarajni).